# Postgres - update multiple columns in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get an error on update multiple columns in a table. Here is my code:

```
UPDATE
  products
SET
  updated_at = 1520581005920, products."categoryId" = t."categoryId"
FROM
  (VALUES (1,2),(3,4)) AS t (id,categoryId)
WHERE
  products.id = t.id AND
  products.store = 1
RETURNING
  products.id,
  products.title,
  products.status,
  products.condition,
  products."productInfo",
  products.price,
  products.note,
  products.created_at,
  products.updated_at
```

The error is: `operator doesn't exist: integer = record`. How should I fix it?

Code for creating the table using Knex.js:

```
await db.schema.createTable('products', function (table) {
  table.increments()
  table.string('title').notNullable()
  table.enu('status', ['sold', 'ordered', 'in-stock']).notNullable()
  table.enu('condition', ['used', 'new']).notNullable()
  table.text('productInfo').defaultTo(null)
  table.decimal('price').notNullable()
  table.text('note').defaultTo(null)
  table.bigInteger('created_at').notNullable()
  table.bigInteger('updated_at').notNullable()
  table.integer('categoryId').references('categories.id').notNullable()
  table.integer('store').references('stores.id').notNullable()
})
```

Comment: from your code I would expect using `= t.categoryId` - without quotes. and error looks irrelevant. hm - can you build reproducable env? scripts or one of "fiddles"?..

Comment: are you sure the data type of products.updated_at  is integer?

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `products`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Still not working

Comment: @Pelin Yes, it is. It's returned by JavaScript `Date.now`

Comment: That's not a `CREATE TABLE` statement, please add the real SQL statement to create the table. But as far as I can tell, there is no `categoryId` column in that table, only a `category` column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, spelling mistake. Fixed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Still not working